# Swift - AWS multipart upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm trying to speed up uploads to my s3 bucket for an iOS client (in Swift). Multipart upload seems like a promising solution but I'm wondering if:

- it would make a difference over normal upload when network reception is just "ok". And generally how much of a speedup should I expect, if any?
- are there good resources out there about this for Swift? The best I could get is https://medium.com/@otusweb/how-to-tame-the-aws-framework-to-upload-a-large-file-to-s3-19430d245510#.fellvgd6b that looks like 200+ lines to handle that logic, with some code that is missing.

Comment: According to this [blog post](https://cyclecomputing.com/multi-threaded-data-transfers-with-s3/) you can get a 2.5x speedup by using multipart uploads on a fast network. Note that the minimum part size is 5MB, so multipart uploads won't help for files smaller than that.

Comment: Thanks. Ok I was excepting quite more and I'm wondering how much I can get on not so fast network. My guess is not that much, and maybe not at all. I'll do more tests though.